# need to find a way to get data inside subdocument in mongo

Tags: mongodb, find, match, element

I need a way to find inside nested array documents.

I want to find value matching inside `street_1`.

this is my query:

```
db.phonebook.find({'address.home.street_1' : 'street 1 result'});
```

and my document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53788c0c74d3ead0098b4568"),
    "first_name" : "jarod",
    "last_name" : "petters",
    "company" : "nostromos",
    "phone_numbers" : [
        {
            "cell" : "0752203337"
        },
        {
            "home" : "0850819201"
        },
        {
            "home" : "0499955550"
        }
    ],
    "website" : "http://www.mywebsite.com",
    "email" : [
        {
            "home" : "email.first.com"
        },
        {
            "office" : "email.second.com"
        }
    ],
    "address" : [
        {
            "home" : {
                "stree_1" : "street 1 result",
                "stree_2" : "",
                "postal_code" : "66502",
                "city" : "my littre city",
                "country" : "usa"
            }
        }
    ],
    "nationality" : "mars",
    "date_of_birth" : "1978-01-01"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is the good one. But your document is not good, you have done a mistake in your document, you write `stree_1` instead of `street_1`. If your document is right, change your query to :
`db.phonebook.find({'address.home.stree_1' : 'street 1 result'});`